# Objective-C: unichar vs. char

Tags: iphone, c, objective-c, unicode

I'm a little confused between a unichar and a char.  Can I treat unichar's similar to char's?

For example, can I do this:

```
-(BOOL)isNewLine:(unichar)c {

if(c == '\n')
  return YES;
else
  return NO;

}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, unichar is internally `unsigned short`, so you can meaningfully compare it with a `char` (if the latter is ASCII, but that works fine for `'\n'`).

Answer (score 6):

Be careful checking for newline that you know the format of your line endings, as Unix (and modern Mac) use \n, but Windows uses \r\n and classic Mac uses \r.

Comment: Thanks.  I've found a class, NSCharacterSet, that has a static method to produce NSNewlineCharacterSet which I can compare against.

Answer (score 0):

When comparing unichars, consider instead using:

```
if ([[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet] characterIsMember:unicharCharacter])
{
    //any type of newline
}
else
{
    //etc
}
```

Then you will catch all types of newlines and have code you can easily modify to match different character sets (like whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet).

This is the big upside with unichars.