# What's wrong with my Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Something's wrong with my code here and I can't quite figure it out.

**Edit:**  Please correct this code.  Thanks!

```
int stringLength = [theData length];
for (int i = 1; i <= stringLength; i++) {
        unichar currentCharacter = [theData characterAtIndex:i];
        int currentCharacterCode = keyCodeForKeyString(currentCharacter);
        CGPostKeyboardEvent((CGCharCode)0, (CGKeyCode)currentCharacterCode, true);
        CGPostKeyboardEvent((CGCharCode)0, (CGKeyCode)currentCharacterCode, false);
}

- (int)keyCodeForKeyString:(unichar)keyString
{
    if (strcmp(keyString, "a") == 0) return 0;
    if (strcmp(keyString, "s") == 0) return 1;
    if (strcmp(keyString, "d") == 0) return 2;
    if (strcmp(keyString, "f") == 0) return 3;
    if (strcmp(keyString, "h") == 0) return 4;
}
```

Comment: what's wrong? what's the error? what is it supposed to do? We are not mind readers....

Comment: it's supposed to run `CGPostKeyboardEvent` (which simulates a keypress in cocoa) from a string of characters.  It's supposed to split up the string in the for loop, find the correct key code, and then place that key code into the `CGPostKeyboardEvent`.  Xcode says `Initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast`, `No '-keyCodeForKeyString' method found`.

Comment: It only runs on OSX, that's the problem!

Answer (score 3):

For one thing, `characterAtIndex` is zero-indexed.  So, you're starting at the second character of theData, and (assuming `theData` and `theString` have the same length) reading one past the end (which is undefined behavior).  For another, `characterAtIndex` returns `unichar`, not a pointer-to-char.  You're also calling keyCodeForKeyString *on* the pointer, when you should be passing it as a parameter.  But you could change `keyCodeForKeyString` to take a unichar, rather than a one-character null-terminated string.

Comment: ah thanks, i figured that [NSString length] started at 1, but i didn't realize that characterAtIndex started at 0.  thanks.

what is a unichar and what do i need to do?

Comment: A `unichar` represents a Unicode code unit.  Internally, it's an unsigned short.  `[NSString length]` does *not* start at 1.  It can be zero, which means the string is empty (and you can't call characterAtIndex).  Also remember zero-indexing implies the last character is length - 1.

Comment: I hate to seem annoying, but could you please correct the code? I'm not getting anywhere. I would learn by seeing what is correct.  Here's what I've got...

`for (int i = 1; i <= stringLength; i++) {
   unichar currentCharacter = [theData characterAtIndex:i];
   int currentCharacterCode = keyCodeForKeyString(currentCharacter);
   CGPostKeyboardEvent((CGCharCode)0, (CGKeyCode)currentCharacterCode, true);
 }
- (int)keyCodeForKeyString:(unichar)keyString
{
if (strcmp(keyString, "a") == 0) return 0;
 if (strcmp(keyString, "s") == 0) return 1;

...
...
`  not sure why it wont format for code...

Comment: @Wind Up, please post your code as an edit to the question.  Then, you can format it properly.  You haven't fixed the loop indices yet.  If you're using `unichar`, you can just compare directly to a character constant (e.g. 'a').  Note the single quotes.  You don't use `strcmp` for that.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092695/objective-c-unichar-vs-char .

Comment: Wind Up Toy: A `unichar` is a single character, just as `char` is. A C string is a *pointer to an array of characters*, typically declared as either `char[]` (e.g., `char str[]`) or `char *` (`char *str`). `strcmp` only takes a C string, and does not know how to deal with C strings made of `unichar`s instead of `char`s. Since you have a single `unichar`, you should simply compare it using the equality operator; `strcmp` is only for C strings of `char`.

Answer (score 3):

This line:

```
int currentCharacterCode = keyCodeForKeyString(currentCharacter);
```

is a problem.  You don't seem to have a function called keyCodeForKeyString.  You do have a method with that name, but the syntax for that would be

```
int currentCharacterCode = [self keyCodeForKeyString: currentCharacter];
//                          ^^^^ I assume you are sending the message from the same object.
```