# NSString and unichar don't match well when it comes to Unicode

Tags: objective-c, string, unicode, character-encoding

The Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/Strings.html) states that

> A string object is implemented as an array of Unicode characters

However, the size of `unichar` data type, which is likely to be `unsigned short` behind the scenes, is only 16 bits, which renders impossible to represent every Unicode character with `unichar`. How do I reconcile these two facts in my mind?

Comment: maybe you should explain why you think it is impossible.

Comment: Most of the time, `NSString` uses an underlying UTF-8 string, not UTF-16, unless you create it with UTF-16, specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that Apple's docs incorrectly refer to Unicode characters when it really means UTF-16 code points.

In the early days of Unicode it was hoped that it would not exceed 16 bits, but it has. Both Apple and Microsoft (and probably others) use 16-bit integers to represent "Unicode characters", even though some characters will have to be represented by surrogate pairs.

Various methods of `NSString` handle this case (plus combining characters) and return a range for a given character. E.g. `-rangeOfCharacterFromSet:...` and `-rangeOfComposedCharacterSequences...`.

Comment: So, does it mean that the documentation is overconfident about Unicode and NSString's implementation currently uses UTF-16 encoding internally (at max) and thus ain't capable of containing, say, Egyptian hieroglyphs?

Comment: Huh? What makes you think that UTF-16 can't represent all of Unicode?

Comment: You're correct, it can :*) But guess what I was thinking of is that one would need to use something else than `unichar` to store characters out of Unicode's BMP to feed NSString with them, right?

Comment: You would need to use a sequence (i.e. array) of `unichar`s, just like what `+[NSString stringWithCharacters:length:]` or `-[NSString initWithCharacters:length:]` accepts. Or, of course, you can use a byte sequence of a given encoding in an array of `NSData` with `-initWithBytes:length:encoding:` or `-initWithData:encoding:`.

Comment: @ken - Where do think the docs are incorrect? I don't see it.

Comment: Every place they refer to "character(s)" but actually mean UTF-16 code points. As OP's question suggests, not all Unicode characters can be represented with a single UTF-16 code point or a single `unichar`. For example `@"\U00010300"` is a string with a single Unicode character, but `-length` gives 2 because `NSString` represents it as two UTF-16 code points, the surrogate pair U+D800,U+DF00.

Comment: @ken - no, it means what it says. [@"\U00010300" length] is 2 because it is two characters U+D800 and U+DF00, paired, to represent one code point - U00010300.

Comment: That's not what Unicode means by "character". A Unicode character is ["The smallest component of written language that has semantic value"](http://www.unicode.org/glossary/#character). What's the semantic value of U+D800? None, because it's not complete. I was mistaken about one bit of terminology. I should have referred to UTF-16 "code units", not "code points". Code points are in the Unicode codespace, not any particular encoding (although they do correspond to UTF-32).

Comment: [The Unicode standard](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode6.1.0/) even says things like, "In the Unicode Standard, specific values of some code units cannot be used to represent an encoded character in isolation. This restriction applies to isolated surrogate code units in UTF-16 and to the bytes 80-FF in UTF-8." (Chapter 3, section 3.9, definition D77)

Answer (score 0):

1. It's not sure that strings are represented by the `unichar` data type. "A string object is implemented as an array of Unicode characters" doesn't mean in the source code it is stored as `unichar *`. You don't know how it is implemented, do you?
2. And what if `unichar` is not an unsigned short? What if it is a 32- or 64-bit data type?

Comment: Isn't the size of a unicode character somethings strange... like a 20-bit or something like that? (In reality is leaves some trailing zeroes)

Comment: No. UTF8 is 8 or 16 or 24 or 32 bit; UTF-16 is 16-bit; UTF-32 is 32-bit.

Comment: See for yourself what number `sizeof(unichar)` evaluates to or have a look at this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092695/objective-c-unichar-vs-char

Comment: Well -- it may be the case that on most systems it's an unsigned short. But it *is* implementation-specific and you must *not* insist on it.

Comment: @H2CO3 Well, UTF is just a set of encodings. All unicode characters (yes, I'm including the emojis as well) actually requires 21-bits to fit.

Comment: What if they extend the set of Unicode characters? (Regarding this, you could say that ASCII characters require 6 bit only, as there are 2 times 26 letters in the English alphabet...)

Comment: The Unicode Consortium has declared that they won't be extending Unicode beyond 0x10FFFF.

Comment: With regard to "'A string object is implemented as an array of Unicode characters' doesn't mean in the source code it is stored as unichar *. You don't know how it is implemented, do you?": the OP wasn't asking about the internals. `NSString` presents an interface/abstraction in terms of "characters" and uses `unichar` to represent them. The primitive methods `-length` and `-characterAtIndex:` deal in `unichar` characters. The docs say "A string object presents itself as an array of Unicode characters". Etc.

Comment: "OP wasn't asking about the internals" -- apparently, he was. He asked how can it be possible to the implementation which presumably does X to also do Y, which might be contradictionary.

Comment: @H2CO3 Come on, I wasn't mentioning the internals of *NSString* in that particular post, only what's behind *unichar*. The rest of your post is an incomprehensible riddle..