# What are %@ these things called - Are they indexed anywhere?

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, variables

What are these things we use in strings called:

•`%@` - string

•`%i` - intiger

•`%f` - float

Do they have names? And is there an index of all the possible `%___` values anywhere?

Comment: `%@` is not `string`. It is for Objective-C objects by calling the objects's `description` method (or possible locale specific variants).

Comment: [Do not use signatures, salutations or taglines in your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are called string format specifier:
Here is the list.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html

Comment: What would `typedef unsigned short unichar;` be? I can't seem to find it... As in: `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", [messagefield.text characterAtIndex:i]]`

Comment: ^%C was just a guess.. I don't know what really goes there... I tried `%@` and I got an error.. it (xCode) "corrected" it to `%hu` which really messed up my code.

Comment: Ah nevermind, turns out my total guess `%c` was just what I needed haha! Thankyou!

Comment: A better link would be the [IEEE printf spec](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html).

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw: `unichar` is explicitly listed in the linked table -- 14th item, after `%g`, `%G`, `%c`. Its specifier is `%C`

Comment: @JoshCaswell Sorry I didn't know to look just for unichar :) I was checking for unsigned short unichar and expecting "%UUC" or something haha!

Answer (score 1):

They are features inherited from C, and they are called string formatter, or in Apple's term, format specifier. In C, they are used to format a `printf` output.

You can find out more on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string), [cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/), or [ADC](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html).

Comment: You can check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092695/objective-c-unichar-vs-char
It seems they are handled as unsigned short. But as for the typedef, we may need sometime to dig it up.

Answer (score 0):

Its the **NSString formatting methods** and **CFString formatting functions** follow the **IEEE** printf specification;

example

```
NSLog(@"%@",yourString];
NSLog(@"%d",yourInt];
NSLog(@"%f",yourFloat];
```